# Remove duplicates while keeping the data from their cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel-formula

I have a list in excel I need to tidy. I need to remove duplicates from column A while keeping the values from the duplicates in column B and concatenating them. Is there a way to do this in excel or Python?

The reason I need to do this is I am working through a list of part numbers and their alternate numbers. Each alternate is displayed in a cell next to it product code. Products with many alternates have many duplicates. There are 29,883 product codes all up.

Any help would be great as I am new to data cleaning.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxdTE.png)

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset= 'A')` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to aggregate the entries of `alt-prod-code` by grouping of `prod-code`.   You can do it as follows:

```
df.groupby('prod-code', as_index=False).agg(','.join)
```

**Input**

```
  prod-code alt-prod-code
0    AB0110    22RB.30606
1    AB0110     22RB30606
```

**Output:**

```
  prod-code         alt-prod-code
0    AB0110  22RB.30606,22RB30606
```

Comment: Answered it exactly! Thanks for the help, I have to have this in tomorrow so you saved my butt.

Comment: @MathewOlwyn  Pleased to help!